# Implementing OAuth 2.0 and OpenId Connect provider using IdentityServer3 with existing login server and membership provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I know that IdentityServer3 provides the whole stack of implementing OAuth 2.0, OpenId Conect etc. I don't know if I should use IdentityServer3. Because I have my own login server which authenticates the user using a membership provider which is already available. Can I integrate my already available login mechanism with IdentityServer3 and implement OAuth 2.0?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the membership part to identityserver is easy. If you want to keep the whole "login experience" just the same but use idsrv for protocol support - this is more work.

You can move your login app into idsrv and use the partial login concept. This requires your existing login page to interact with the idsrv OWIN extension methods.

Another option is to encapsulate your login app as Katana authentication middleware and plug it into idsrv as an external provider.

Comment: No, our login server talks to memebership and authenticates the user. Out membership server is capable of generating the access_token and refresh_token based. I dont know if I should user idsrv or just write my own oAuth server using the existing login and membership server.