# Programatically create an OpenID Connect id_token with IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3

I am adding IdentityServer3 on to an existing website (NopCommerce to be specific). It has it's own registration and authentication system, but we need to also offer OpenID Connect so that a back end application can be integrated. Calls to the back end need to have an id_token for the current user that the back end validates to confirm the identity.

I've found information about how to use an existing membership database to provide the user data for IdentityServer3 to check, however I am bit stuck on how to generate the id_token for each user. I guess the obvious answer is to replace the website login with IdentityServer, however that raises further issues for the rest of the project. Ideally I'd like the user to log in as normal and then call a method in IdentityServer to generate the id_token.

Is this possible? I've been hunting around, but can't find anything so far. The best I found was an answer to [programmatically sign in to identityserver3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949893/programmatically-sign-in-to-identityserver3). I think it's suggesting making a HTTP post to IdentityServer, but it feels kind of hacky.

I also found [Implementing OAuth 2.0 and OpenId Connect provider using IdentityServer3 with existing login server and membership provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002318/implementing-oauth-2-0-and-openid-connect-provider-using-identityserver3-with-ex), but I have to admit it's assuming quite a bit of knowledge I don't have (yet).

Comment: I've tried the code to [programmatically sign in to identityserver3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949893/programmatically-sign-in-to-identityserver3) and realised that this always returns an access_token, Unfortunately the back end has to have the id_token.

Comment: see this class: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/Default/DefaultTokenService.cs - provided you can instatiate it, you can probably generate an id_token with it

Comment: Thanks for finding the class I think the key part though is in "_if_ I can instantiate it". So far I've implemented a simple IdentityServer as suggested by JohnC in his answer and am exploring how well that suits our requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution based on John C's answer worked using a NopCommece external authentication plugin, but I was unhappy with having to leave Nop to authenticate and register when IdentityServer was using the Nop database. Going via the external auth route seemed to be the only way to get an OpenID Connect id_token. After a break and some time to revisit the code though I found the following:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/serviceFactory.html
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/serviceFactory.html

By implementing custom services, IdentityServer allows you to mess with the token creation and generation AND the dependency injection system it uses gives you access to instatiated versions of the default services.

Previously I had followed an answer which sent a username and password to the token endpoint. The OpenID specs say that this should only return the access_token, which is exactly what DefaultTokenService in IdenttyService does. By adding a CustomTokenResponseGenerator however, I was able to re-use the request to create and return an id_token too.

CustomTokenResponse class:

```
internal class CustomTokenResponseGenerator : ICustomTokenResponseGenerator
{

    protected ITokenService _tokenService;

    public CustomTokenResponseGenerator(ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public Task<TokenResponse> GenerateAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request, TokenResponse response)
    {
        var tokenRequest = new TokenCreationRequest
        {
            Subject = request.Subject,
            Client = request.Client,
            Scopes = request.ValidatedScopes.GrantedScopes,
            //Nonce = request.AuthorizationCode.Nonce,

            ValidatedRequest = request
        };
        var idToken = _tokenService.CreateIdentityTokenAsync(tokenRequest);
        idToken.Wait();
        var jwt = _tokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(idToken.Result);
        response.IdentityToken = jwt.Result;
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

How to inject the custom service in Startup.cs:

```
 factory.TokenService = new Registration<ITokenService, TokenService>();
 factory.CustomTokenResponseGenerator = new Registration<ICustomTokenResponseGenerator, CustomTokenResponseGenerator>();
```

Comment: It looks like in your code that you are calling a async method without using the await keyword in front of it. If that method is truly a async method, you need to add the async keyword before your method GenerateAsync, and then use the await keyword when calling CreateIdentityTokenAsync and CreateSecurityTokenAsync. Then just return response by itself, without the FromResult.

Comment: @Suddy you are registering a TokenService here, what is it? IS3 doesn't have anything other than a DefaultTokenService, did you create a custom one?

Comment: Figured it out, simply changing to DefaultTokenService works fine: `factory.TokenService = new Registration<ITokenService, DefaultTokenService>();`

Answer (score 0):

When user logs-in into NopCommerce application, you can send an HTTP authorize request to identityserver. Make sure while sending the authorize request to idsrv you are using prompt=none, this way you will get the id_token or access_token without showing a consent to the user again if the user is already logged-in.

```
    function getAuthorizeRequest() {
var url = global.appSettings.identityServerURL
                    + "/connect/authorize?client_id=siteB&response_type=id_token token&redirect_uri="
                    + global.appSettings.siteBUrl + "/Main/NopCommerceapp&scope=siteBscope openid email roles&prompt=none&nonce="76767xz676xzc76xz7c67x6c76"                       
return encodeURI(url);}
```

**Checkout idsrv authorize endpoint** https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not quite sure I follow. The docs say "no UI will be shown during the request. If this is not possible (e.g. because the user has to sign in or consent) an error is returned". My user has logged into NopCommerce, but isn't logged into IdentityServer and so they are just getting an error response.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution would be to implement IdentityServer3 and get it reading from your existing Nop membership database. Then create a Web API app that runs on its own that utilizes your IdentityServer3 setup. Inside the Web API, you implement all the functionality that your back end app needs, reading and writing to the Nop database.

Keep your Nop frontend UI separate from your backend API. If you follow the two links below, you should be able to get something up and running pretty quickly.

[Creating the simplest OAuth2 Authorization Server, Client and API](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html)
[MVC Authentication & Web APIs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html)

Comment: Thanks. I took the simple server approach with a customer user service (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html) that reads form my Nop customer database. Nop is able to user it as an external login provider (http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/External+Authentication+Method).